# How can I put specific Coordinates in an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, coordinates

in Swift Playgrounds I have solved a level where I had to place 16 Blocks at specific coordinates.

for example:

*let B1 = Block;
world.place(B1, atColumn: 1, row: 6)*

If you have to do this 16 times, it is  kind of lot to write down and doesn’t look really good. So my Question is if it is possible to create an array with coordinates (if yes, how can I do that) to just need to write something like that:

*world.place(Block(), at: coordinate)*

Thank you already for your time and your answers.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to work with 2D array instead?

Comment: I am just using the App on my iPad on the moment. Do not really now how an 2D array works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of named tuples and then loop over that array placing a block at each one:

```
let coordinates: [(column: Int, row: Int)] = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

for coordinate in coordinates {
    let B1 = Block
    world.place(B1, atColumn: coordinate.column, row: coordinate.row)
}
```

or you can unpack the `column` and `row` directly by using:

```
for (column, row) in coordinates {
    let B1 = Block
    world.place(B1, atColumn: column, row: row)
}
```